# What is an expansion tank for?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

Somebody told me I need an expansion tank on my water heater. I'm just not sure why. Can someone please help me understand?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to DIY. First hit from Google: https://www.4abc.com/blog/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-water-heater-expansion-tank If you need other info, please be more specific in your question.

Comment: It felt very specific. Thank you for the link.

Comment: When heated water will expand due to increase in pressure. That expansion will go to the expansion tank for later use. If no expansion tank it has nowhere to go other than overpressure valve release to the outside or back in the cold water supply since its pressure is higher than the cold water supply pressure (back-flow)

Comment: Sizing is important. The expansion of water is not trivial -- from cold to near-boiling is about 4% expansion. An expansion vessel is normally pre-pressurised to 3.5 bar and should open the external pressure vent at 6 bar. So you can only use less than half the volume in the expansion vessel before the pressure doubles. The pressure vessel needs to be a volume of at least 10% of the water being heated: a 180-litre water heater needs an 18-litre expansion vessel.

Answer (score 9):

It depends upon your water supply. Like Ruskes said, when water gets heated, it expands. If you are on a well or water system w/o a check valve, the supply simply gets fed back the tiny amount of expansion. If you do have check valves, yes, you need an expansion tank. I had a rental where the water company, due to new regulations, had to install water meters w/check valves. Then, after lots of hot water use, the TPR valve on the WH started leaking.  I put a pressure gauge on the WH and it was over 110 PSI at times after heavy hot water use. I installed an expansion tank and it cured the problem.

Comment: Typical well system has a pressure tank, which is functionally a very large expansion tank. The water doesn't go back to the well.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, ThreePaseEel. !

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Just to be clear,    I never said expansion would go back into the well,  I know way better than that.  I mentioned that it was a "tiny amount" that might backflow in a well / pressure tank system.   If somebody doesn't realize pressure tanks on well systems can take a tiny bit of back flow,   they need to learn more about systems of that type.

Comment: TPR = Temperature/pressure-relief (I wasn't sure exactly what it stood for so I looked it up.)

Comment: ANYTIME a check valve, back-flow preventer device, is located on the main water line feeding the house it creates a closed system and therefore requires some type of expansion relief device. In some instances homes will have a check valve installed on the house side of the well's pressure tank and does require one.